# Remove author prefix on WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

How can I remove the author prefix on a WordPress website, I have done a quick Google but have only found htaccess redirects which I don't want to resort to.

To clarify I want to turn this:

`http://www.domain.com/author/cameron/`

into this

`http://www.domain.com/cameron/`

I don't want to use any redirects of any kind, but actual PHP code I can use in the functions.php file, as I want all links across the site that use the author stuff to auto update without keeping there original links and then redirecting to the new one.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't recommend that!  The `/author/` tag is used to namespace your authors.  Removing it will confuse WordPress if you ever have a page named 'cameron' since pages are automatically used in permalinks like this by default.

Comment: No different than removing the `/category/` prefix. My client has requested this as they want the urls to match the posts which are currently like this `domain.com/cameron/2010/post-title/`

Do you know how to remove the author prefix? Thanks.

Comment: The 'WP No Category Base' plugin (http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) source code should give you a good starting point. The basic idea is to add WP rewrite rules which match the names of each of your authors.

Comment: Had a look at that plugin, seems like a super solution. Tried to edit it to do the author prefix instead but it just broke my blog, probably because I'm not 100% sure of what to change (changing category to author doesn't seem to be the best of ideas) Would you or anyone else be able to help with modding this to work for authors? Thanks

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You basically need to add WP rewrite rules to match the names of each of your users in the desired form. This is what the [WP No Category Base](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/) does for categories, so most of the code in my answer is adapted from that plugin.

The primary part of the plugin is a function which hooks into the `author_rewrite_rules` filter and replaces the author rewrite rules. This retrieves all the user names and adds a rewrite rule specifically for each user (the below won't handle feeds, so look at the WP No Category Base source if you need that).

```
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'no_author_base_rewrite_rules');
function no_author_base_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) { 
    global $wpdb;
    $author_rewrite = array();
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename AS nicename from $wpdb->users");    
    foreach($authors as $author) {
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
    }   
    return $author_rewrite;
}
```

The other key part of the plugin is a function which hooks into the `author_link` filter and removes the 'author' base from the returned URL.

```
add_filter('author_link', 'no_author_base', 1000, 2);
function no_author_base($link, $author_id) {
    $link_base = trailingslashit(get_option('home'));
    $link = preg_replace("|^{$link_base}author/|", '', $link);
    return $link_base . $link;
}
```

See this gist: http://gist.github.com/564465

This doesn't handle redirection from the old style author URLs, again, see the WP No Category Base source if you need to do that.

Comment: Thanks @Cameron, I used this code, it's perfect! :)

Answer (score 1):

Be sure to replace this piece of code inside no_author_base_rewrite_rules() :

```
foreach($authors as $author) {
  $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
  $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';

  $rules = get_option( 'rewrite_rules' );
  if ( ! isset( $rules['({$author->nicename})/?$'] ) ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
      $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
  }
}
```

So that Wordpress refreshes the rewrite list. (otherwise some links may not work).