# Wordpress Author Permalinks

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I know how to change the base of the author permalinks, however on my site, I refer to users not by their username but by a number based on their User ID, so User number 5 wrote this post, rather than JohnDoe123 wrote this post.

The problem comes when I go to that users archives and instead of seeing something like example.com/authors/5/ I see example.com/authors/johndoe123/ .

How do I change permalinks so that I can pull up author archives using the following structure? :

[wordpress_site_url]/authors/[user_ID]/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be done by adding new rewrite rules for each user in exactly the same way you would when changing or removing the author base. So, adapting code from a [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629323/remove-author-prefix-on-wordpress/3639232#3639232), you would add your rewrite rules something like this:

```
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'my_author_url_with_id_rewrite_rules');
function my_author_url_with_id_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) {
  global $wpdb;
  $author_rewrite = array();
  $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT ID, user_nicename AS nicename from {$wpdb->users}");    
  foreach ($authors as $author) {
    $author_rewrite["authors/{$author->ID}/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=' . $author->nicename . '&paged=$matches[1]';
    $author_rewrite["authors/{$author->ID}/?$"] = "index.php?author_name={$author->nicename}";
  }
  return $author_rewrite;
}
```

And then filter the author link:

```
add_filter('author_link', 'my_author_url_with_id', 1000, 2);
function my_author_url_with_id($link, $author_id) {
  $link_base = trailingslashit(get_option('home'));
  $link = "authors/$author_id";
  return $link_base . $link;
}
```

---

Actually I don't think you need to create rules for each user in this case, the following two rules should suffice:

```
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'my_author_url_with_id_rewrite_rules');
function my_author_url_with_id_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) {
  $author_rewrite = array();
  $author_rewrite["authors/([0-9]+)/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
  $author_rewrite["authors/([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author=$matches[1]';
  return $author_rewrite;
}
```

Comment: I have a couple of questions on this if possible. 1. does `author_rewrite_rules` run on every page load? 2. are you only able to remove the loop because the users are referred to by their IDs? what if users were referred to by their usernames?