# How to remove author base in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting

Standard author links in WordPress look like: `example.com/author/johnsmith`

I'd like to remove the `author/` part of the URL so the username is in the root. For example: `example.com/johnsmith`

I control page creation on my site so there will be no chance of a conflict in page and author name.

So far I've tried the following solution from [WP Snippet](http://wp-snippet.com/remove-author-prefix-from-slug) but this no longer seems to work:

```
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'no_author_base_rewrite_rules');
function no_author_base_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) {
    global $wpdb;
    $author_rewrite = array();
    $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename AS nicename from $wpdb->users");   
    foreach($authors as $author) {
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
        $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
    }  
    return $author_rewrite;
}


add_filter('author_link', 'no_author_base', 1000, 2);
function no_author_base($link, $author_id) {
    $link_base = trailingslashit(get_option('home'));
    $link = preg_replace("|^{$link_base}author/|", '', $link);
    return $link_base . $link;
}
```

Do anyone know if there is a working solution to this?

Comment: There are several WP plugins offering this kind of capability. You may do better asking about this at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I've searched the WP repository and can't find any. Are you able to provide some links?

Comment: "author slug" as a search on the WP plugin repository finds several.

Comment: sorry, I should have said i can't find 'a working' plugin :)

Comment: I did an medium in-depth search in [wp-hackers], core.trac.wordpress.org and [wordpress.se]. Also for some `htaccess` here at [so]. Couldn't find any working solution :/ . . . . . Right now, I can only think of creating a page/post for each author (where we can set the permalinks easily) or doing something with the hook [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect).

Comment: @brasofilo thanks for the suggestion but I was hoping to remove the base slug from the author archive in an automated way. Creating a new page each time an author registers will be more work than I can handle

Comment: Yep, seems a waste considering that a tweak should fix the URL... anyway, here's an [automated way](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/89520/create-an-author-page-on-registration) to create pages for users. I'll keep this post in my favorites, good luck!

Answer (score 4):

I've tested this combined solution but wasn't working before regenerating of permalinks. You can do it, as brasfolio described : simply clicking save on permalink page in dashboard.

```
add_filter('author_rewrite_rules', 'no_author_base_rewrite_rules');
function no_author_base_rewrite_rules($author_rewrite) {
   global $wpdb;
   $author_rewrite = array();
   $authors = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT user_nicename AS nicename from $wpdb->users");   
   foreach($authors as $author) {
       $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
       $author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]';
   }  
   return $author_rewrite;
}

if( !is_admin() ) {
add_action('init', 'author_rewrite_so_22115103');
}

function author_rewrite_so_22115103() {
   global $wp_rewrite; 
   if( 'author' == $wp_rewrite->author_base ) $wp_rewrite->author_base = null;
}
```

Comment: I've removed my answer (using `global $wp_rewrite`) until able to fully debug it.

Comment: you need a filter for WP_Rewrite. other ways, when processing url it will have 404 error (will treat it as a post). use author_rewrite_rules In fact I've managed today to make it working (your code with add_filter code from question). Try it.

Comment: Hi Michal S, thanks for this. It still doesn't seem to work for me? Not sure why! I think a combination of both your approach e.g. `author_rewrite_rules` and b__'s approach might work. @b__ are you able to repost your solution so we can all try to debug it? Thanks again to everyone

Comment: where is your problem: author links on pages are wrong or when use them is 404?

Comment: With this approach, nothing happens. My author links are still `site.com/author/user`. @b__'s approach resulted in author links like `site.com/user` but broke the rest of the pages on my site.

Comment: Also, even if I could get your solution to work, I would need to flush rewrite rules on each new user sign up because the new user wouldn't have been part of the foreach loop that had previously run

Comment: I was hoping a combination of both your solution and b__'s would do the trick. e.g hook b__'s function to `author_rewrite_rules` - maybe??

Comment: I've been wondering why looping through all of the authors is needed?

Comment: My code infact contains b__ solution - you should have site.com/name links. Foreach loop is trying to fit part to url to author one by one, if it fits opens by normal default get method. Test the filter again, if fails make rewrite function simpler like: $author_rewrite["test"] = 'index.php?author_name=michal and AFTER CLICK SAVE in premalinks try site.com/test (tested toady)

Comment: after saving permalinks, check them in DB, table ..._options record rewrite_rules values are serialized, but easy to spot.

Comment: How can I avoid having to loop through each author? When a new author registers, the new author hasn't been part of the loop yet, so until I manually flush permalinks again, the new author's page is `example.com/author/username` where the rest of the authors on the site are `example.com/username`. The reason I liked b__'s solution was mainly because it didn't need to loop through all of the authors. Also permalinks didn't need to be flushed on each new author registration.

Comment: you named a solution ;) after new author added we need to have a hooked action of rewriting rule record. (will try to add it today) But just to point out: even without it, new author has short url on pages (as a not working link) - this part (wrote by b__) doesn't need a loop. Loop take action to write rules for wp to process the url from browser.

Answer (score 2):

Your code appears fine. Manually flush your permalink structure to reflect these changes.

```
1)  Settings -> Permalinks -> choose default -> Save
2)  Revert the settings to original.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try: RedirectMatch 301 ^/author/(.+)$ http://www.yourblog.com/$1

This will go in your .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Also add this near the other similar two, in order to redirect the feeds as well:

```
$author_rewrite["({$author->nicename})/page/?([0-9]+)/?$"] = 'index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems we have to refresh permalinks structure, but each time someone registered a new rule.

So try to flush it automatically with this :

```
$wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
```

In your *functions.php* file.

I had the same problem but with this it seems to be ok.
But there's still a problem of conflict with page & post name.

Answer (score -1):

This Question is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3629323/remove-author-prefix-on-wordpress)...

You can do something like [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3639232).
This is nearly what you wanted..

Hope this will work...

Comment: Hi - thanks for your answer. Is the solution you linked to identical to the solution I said no longer works? Please see my question.