# Getting Wordpress to accept variable URLs

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, url-routing

A couple of months ago, I built **this lead dashboard** (*) in pure PHP.

A key feature of my lead dashboard is that it's very flexible in its URL parsing. Parameters can be added to the end of the URL and the order or quantity really doesn't matter. See examples below.

I'm currently porting my dashboard to a Wordpress system and would like to maintain this same flexibility, but it's not really clear to me what would be a good strategy in Wordpress to implement this routing technique. Should I go for an `.htaccess` based solution? Should I add a filter? Should I add an action? And which filter or action would seem the most suitable?

Any suggestions on how to do this the right way?

---

Example URL 1 :

```
http://www.johnslegers.com/lead-dashboard/
```

Example URL 2 :

```
http://www.johnslegers.com/lead-dashboard/keyword:Stackoverflow
```

Example URL 3 :

```
http://www.johnslegers.com/lead-dashboard/keyword:Stackoverflow/language:English
```

Example URL 4 :

```
http://www.johnslegers.com/lead-dashboard/language:English,Dutch/keyword:Stackoverflow,problem
```

Example URL 5 :

```
http://www.johnslegers.com/lead-dashboard/value:3500/percentage:5,15,30,50,70/language:English,French,German/keyword:Stackoverflow,problem
```

Example URL 6 :

```
http://www.johnslegers.com/lead-dashboard/keyword:Stackoverflow,%20programming,%20code,%20Wordpress,%20problem/language:English/currency:US%20Dollars/percentage:5,10,20,50,85/cost:0.9,9,34,108/value:5400
```

---

**EDIT :**

(*) Google decided to impose an [**RMF policy**](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements) that requires any dev to implement a long list of features of they want to use their Adwords API. Because my app uses only a few features of Adwords and thus doesn't comply with this policy, Google no longer allows me to access their API. This means that the tool no longer functions correctly and cannot be fixed unless Google decides to change their policy. Because the tool no longer functions correctly, I removed the link.

Comment: use native rewrite rule system, add custom filters, read http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule and this as a sample of possibilities http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115103/how-to-remove-author-base-in-wordpress/22194527#22194527

Comment: @MichalS : Thanks for your links, but that doesn't really help. How do I allow (1) any number of parameters in my URL and (2) a totally random order of those parameters?

Comment: When you have always "/lead-dashboard/" it's easy, follow this tutorial http://www.wpexplorer.com/the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Comment: @MichalS : Your tutorial only explains how to pass one or two parameters in a fixed order. That doesn't help me for my use case. I need to know how to pass a RANDOM number of paramaters in a RANDOM order as shown in the examples above. When my URL is 'leaddashboard/A/B/C/D/E', I need to pass 'A/B/C/D/E'. When my URL is 'leaddashboard/C/D/E', I need to pass 'C/D/E'. When my URL is 'leaddashboard/F/A/C', I need to pass 'F/A/C'. etc.

Comment: I got it. I'm not placing answers, just directions. I was hoping it was helpful. If not, when I got some time, will write and test complete solution (after simply mistakes done, I'll never publish without test).

Comment: By the way, the link you posted seems unusable for me. It opened, and an overlay appeared saying 'Please wait' and just stayed there.

Comment: @Lee : Unfortunately, Google decided to impose an RMF policy (https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/requirements) that requires any dev to implement a long list of features of they want to use their Analytics API. Because my app uses only a few features of Analytics and thus doesn't comply with this policy, Google no longer allows me to access their API. This means that the tool no longer functions correctly and cannot be fixed unless Google decides to change their policy.

Comment: @Lee : I added this information to my original question in a note at the bottom.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving this issue myself.

To fix my problem, I just had to add the following action function to the `functions.php` file of my theme :

```
function simulationpage_init() {
    // Remember to flush the rules once manually after you added this code!
    add_rewrite_rule(
            // The regex to match the incoming URL
            'simulatie/.*',
            // The resulting internal URL
            'index.php?pagename=simulatie&data=$matches[1]',
            // This is a rather specific URL, so we add it to the top of the list
            'top');

    flush_rewrite_rules();
}

add_action('init', 'simulationpage_init');
```

That achieved exactly what I wanted!