# Wordpress, custom mod_rewirte in .htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I want do add my own rules in .htaccess in Wordpress.

i have something like this

http://page.com/materialy/?id_s=2&nazwa=stale-niestopowe

i want something like this:

http://page.com/materialy/s/2/stale-niestopowe

i tried some plugins in wp but it dosent work, because in my custom page i use [insert_php]

how to edit .htaccess to make that work?

Please help!

Comment: use native worpdress permalinks! http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks

Comment: i use permalinks. but in my custom page i use my own php code and my own variables.

Comment: Great. Then add rewrite rules to your own generated links. See this as an example of adding custom rule http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115103/how-to-remove-author-base-in-wordpress/22194527#22194527

Comment: I add to functions.php my rules. i flush them and not working

Comment: this was just a sample, workin with 'author_rewrite_rules' you need to add custom one, follow this tutorial http://www.wpexplorer.com/the-wordpress-rewrite-api/

Comment: yea.. all working i just forget to reqister query vars and get into my code. thanks this tutorial was great!

Comment: I'm glad, I was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it manually, follow these steps.

open the **.htaccess** file and edit it. add these lines

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ /materialy/?id_s=$1&nazwa=$2 [L]
```

**output:**

http://www.page.com/2/stale-niestopowe.html